# Can anybody make a copy of this jquery effect?

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying for hours to copycat this http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/ expanding ball demo and I am failing every time. Can anybody help and make a copy on jsfiddle?

Comment: What does being a girl have to do with the question?

Comment: im a gurl too :3 plz like this post :3

Comment: please give us an example of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Checkout the demo](http://jsbin.com/anoqik)

---

**CSS (to make it round):**

```
-moz-border-radius:360px;
 -webkit-border-radius:360px;
 border-radius:360px;
```

**jQuery:**

```
var origWidth, origHeight, inrease = 50;

$('#hello').hover(function(){
  origWidth = $(this).width();
  origHeight = $(this).height();  
  
  // expand it
  $(this).animate({width:origWidth + inrease, height:origHeight + inrease});
  
}, function(){
  $(this).animate({width:origWidth, height:origHeight});
});
```

Comment: actually even now I cant get it running. Can you inspect my code? bellated.us.lt/supersized/index.html

Answer (score 2):

You can find the relevant code in the html (it's a [referenced js](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/js/supersized-project.js)):

```
    $('.circle-wrap').hover(
        function(){
            $('.circle',this)
                .stop()
                .animate({width : '150px', height : '150px', 'margin-top' : '-75px', 'margin-left' : '-75px'  }, 200);
        },
        function(){
            $('.circle',this)
                .stop()
                .animate({width : '100px', height : '100px', 'margin-top' : '-50px', 'margin-left' : '-50px'  }, 100);
        }
    );
```

Just use a browser with an "inspect element" feature (firefox has firebird, opera has dragonfly, safari and chrome have similar features) and follow the trail to the function.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it, note in IE you will have boxes rather than circles.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ySZVw/5/)**

**JS**

```
 $('.ball').hover(function(){
     $(this).animate({width : '250px', height : '250px', lineHeight : '250px'}, 500);
        }, 
 function(){
     $(this).stop().animate({width : '200px', height : '200px', lineHeight : '200px'}, 500)
         });
```

**CSS**

```
.ball{
    -webkit-border-radius:250px;
    -moz-border-radius: 250px;
    border-radius: 250px;
    background: green;
    width : 200px;
    height : 200px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
}
```

**Markup**

```
<div class="ball">Demo</div>
```

**CSS3 option**

**[CSS3 animation demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZYZLT/2/)**

```
.ball{
    -webkit-border-radius:250px;
    -moz-border-radius: 250px;
    border-radius: 250px;
    background: green;
    width : 200px;
    height : 200px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
    transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
    transform:scale(1,1);
    -webkit-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;    
    -webkit-transform:scale(1,1);
    -moz-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;    
    -moz-transform:scale(1,1);        
}

.ball:hover{
 transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
 transform:scale(1.5,1.5);   
 -webkit-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;    
 -webkit-transform:scale(1.5,1.5);    
 -moz-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;    
 -moz-transform:scale(1.5,1.5);    
}
```

Comment: actually even now I cant get it running. Can you inspect my code? http://bellated.us.lt/supersized/index.html

Answer (score 1):

- View source -> those two elements are with a `circle` class, wrapped in `circle-wrap`.
- Open `supersized-project.js`. There's the source you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A small observation of the code and you find these...
JS

```
/* Circle Expansion
-----------------------*/       
$('.circle-wrap').hover(
    function(){
        $('.circle',this)
            .stop()
            .animate({width : '150px', height : '150px', 'margin-top' : '-75px', 'margin-left' : '-75px'  }, 200);
    },
    function(){
        $('.circle',this)
            .stop()
            .animate({width : '100px', height : '100px', 'margin-top' : '-50px', 'margin-left' : '-50px'  }, 100);
    }
);
```

CSS

```
.circle-wrap{ width:150px; height:150px; text-align:center; position:absolute; float:left; text-decoration:none; }  
    .circle-wrap .circle{ position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%;  height:100px; width:100px; display:block; overflow:hidden; margin:-50px 0 0 -50px; background:#7bbe31; -moz-border-radius:75px; -webkit-border-radius:75px; border-radius:75px; }
    .circle-wrap .label{ z-index:5; position:relative; top:50%; width:100%; display:block; margin-top:-7px; color:#fff; text-align:center; text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #6caf1f; font:bold 16px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; line-height:14px; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; }
    .demo-circle{ top:100px; left:200px; }
    .download-circle{ top:100px; left:350px; }
        .download-circle .label{ text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000; }
        .download-circle .circle{ background:#0a0a0a; }
```

On a side note, this website has some awesomely commented/written code o: